# Inserción de registros con csv atraves de java

Tags: java, mysql, csv, jdbc, prepared-statements

tengo un problema a la hora de querer insertar unos registros en una base de datos de mysql workbench, traigo los datos desde un archivo csv y estoy usando java para ello, ya tengo unos métodos para leer en si el archivo y los datos que contiene, pero a la hora de insertarlos (son 4 datos básicos: "Código,Jornada,Grupo,Profesor") se registran en un solo atributo de la tabla sql los 4 datos es decir , en el atributo código por ejemplo, registra los 4 datos y los demás atributos en la tabla que en este caso seria Jornada,Grupo,Profesor me los deja vacíos.

```
import Controlador.cls_Conexion;
import Vista.frm_Excel;
import com.csvreader.CsvReader;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;`

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class cls_DeArchivo {
    cls_Conexion objConexion = new cls_Conexion();
    
    public void paGrupoo(){
        List<cls_Datos> Grupo = new ArrayList<cls_Datos>();        
        Grupo = ImportarGrupo();    
        Insertando(Grupo);
    }
    
    public static List <cls_Datos> ImportarGrupo(){
        List <cls_Datos> Grupo = new ArrayList<cls_Datos>();
        
        try {
            CsvReader Leergrupo = new CsvReader(frm_Excel.AQUIRUTA);                       
            Leergrupo.readHeaders();
            
            while(Leergrupo.readRecord()){
                String Codigo = Leergrupo.get(0);
                String Jornada = Leergrupo.get(1);
                String Grupito = Leergrupo.get(2);
                String Profesor =Leergrupo.get(3);
                Grupo.add(new cls_Datos(Codigo,Jornada,Grupito,Profesor));
                System.out.println(Codigo);
            }
           Leergrupo.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No ha sido posible"+ e);          
        }
        
        return Grupo;
        
    }
    
    public static void Insertando (List <cls_Datos> Grupo){
        try {
            cls_Conexion objConexion = new cls_Conexion();
            objConexion.conectar();
            
            objConexion.sql= objConexion.con.prepareStatement("Insert into Grupoo(Codigo,Jornada,Grupo,Profesor) values (?,?,?,?)");
            
            for(int i=0;i<Grupo.size();i++){               
                objConexion.sql.setString(1, Grupo.get(i).getCodigo());
                objConexion.sql.setString(2, Grupo.get(i).getGrupo());
                objConexion.sql.setString(3, Grupo.get(i).getJornada());
                objConexion.sql.setString(4, Grupo.get(i).getProfesor());
                objConexion.sql.execute();                
            }     
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`(null, "guardado");
            
        } catch (HeadlessException | SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ""+ e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: las convenciones de nombrado de variables que usas dificultan leer el código, infiero que usas JDBC pero tampoco lo tengo muy claro

Comment: si, estoy usando el jdbc

Comment: Podrías postear el código del objeto `cls_Datos`?